# How can I remove eventlistener with this function

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am a beginner with JavaScript events and I saw the below code when I was working.

I knew that I must have single function when add and remove the event Listener, so looking in my code :

```
document.getElementById("formId").addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
                event = event || window.event;
                if (event.preventDefault) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                } else {
                    event.returnValue = false;
                }
            });
```

**How can I remove this event listener?**

This is made by the submission event, so when I want to remove this event listener, how can I capture this event to use it again to remove the event listener by the above function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the event listener as follows: `document.getElementById("formId").removeEventListener('submit', handleSubmit);`

Full code example:

```
function handleSubmit(event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    if (event.preventDefault) {
        event.preventDefault();
    } else {
        event.returnValue = false;
    }
}
document.getElementById("formId").addEventListener("submit", handleSubmit);

document.getElementById("formId").removeEventListener("submit", handleSubmit);
```

More options in the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener

Comment: @Steven there was a typo in the function name `handleSubmit`. I assume you just copied the code and this is the reason why it did not work.

Comment: @Devidas : i noticed that and it's working fine , thank you very much , but i have a question , how is the event available in case the removeEventListner calling?

Comment: @Steven I'm not sure I understand your question

Comment: ok i will try to describe, i know that the parameter event in function scope when calling addEventListener is available as window.event but how is the same parameter is also available correctly in case of removeEventListener because there is no event in the time of removing event listner

Comment: i mean in adding the eventListener , the current event is submit object , so the function will be filled like handleSubmit("submit Object") , but in case removeEventListener , no events will be in this time. ?

Comment: in code : 'function handleSubmit(event) {  console.log(event); 
    event = event || window.event;
    if (event.preventDefault) {
        event.preventDefault();
    } else {
        event.returnValue = false;
    }
}' the console.log will work only in case adding , because the event argument will be available in this time , but in case removeEvent Lisnter , the event will be empty , is that right and clearly?

Comment: This is because you do not remove the event. You remove the listener on `submit` action which performs `handleSubmit` function. This means that the event will still be fired as usual.

Comment: that means the submission event will be available always after the submission happened?

Comment: Yes. Also if your initial question is answered please mark it so that others can save time. If you have more question please create a new post.